# Problemas al Instalar Laravel Homestead con Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

actualmente tengo el siguiente inconveniente de instalación, estoy intentando instalar Laravel Homestead a través de vagrant pero cuando ejecuto el comando desde el Git Bash:

`$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

En vez de permitirme elegir la instalación para virtualbox el automaticamente comienza a descargar la de vmware como se aprecia:

```html
    $ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v6.2.0) for provider: vmware_desktop
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.2.0/providers/vmware_desktop.box
==> box: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
    box: Progress: 0% (Rate: 499k/s, Estimated time remaining: 1:09:50)
```

Probé con diferentes versiones de vagrant entre la versión 2.1 y la versión 2.0 y ambas tienen el mismo comportamiento. No he permitido que se ejecute la descarga porque asumo que no funcionará para virtualbox,

¿Alguien sabe como puedo descargarme laravel homestead para virtualbox? ya que con ese comando no funciona. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de investigar en la red logré resolver el problema, pero antes me gustaría dejar claro el porque del problema.

Vagrant a partir de la versión: v6.2.0 no tiene en sus repos a virtualbox ni a parallels, solo tiene a vmware_desktop. Como se puede apreciar en su URL: [Versiones de Vagrant](https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead) es para la versión 6.1.0 que funciona correctamente, para poder instalar laravel/homestead para virtualbox utilicé los siguientes comandos:

```
$ vagrant box add "laravel/homestead" --provider="virtualbox"

$ vagrant init laravel/homestead \

--box-version 6.1.0

$ vagrant up
```

Espero que si alguien más se encuentra en esta misma situación lo pueda resolver de la misma manera.

Feliz Día.